# biblatex ieee customisation

Tags: biblatex

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=ieee,maxbibnames=999]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Labov1972,
    Address = {Philadelphia},
    Author = {William Labov},
    Publisher = {University of Pennsylvania Press},
    Title = {Sociolinguistic Patterns},
    Year = {1972}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
The \cite{Labov1972} said.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Which gives me

[image]

I'd like to see the author name automatically added to the citation label

[image]

Is it possible to do it globally so that I don't have to write the name manually before every `\cite`?.

Answer (score 1):

seems like `\textcite` instead of `\cite` solved it